# Changing PyScripter to work with different Python Versions

Tags: python, pyscripter

I'm using [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) for writing python programs and I can't figure out how to make it work with Python26 on my computer. When I installed ArcGIS, by default it installs Python26. I then installed PyScripter which found that installation and it worked fine. Later, I installed Python27, and subsequently reinstalled PyScripter.Now Pyscripter uses Python27 and I don't know how to change it.

I've looked at the settings under `Tools -> PythonPath` and they are as follows:

[image]

and also `Tools -> Configure Tools`

[image]

[image]

I assume I need to change the python path entries, but what do I change them to? My Python26 installation is found in C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Bin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you go to the pyScripter folder in the start menu, it will have a version of pyScripter for Python 2.4 to 3.2. Just run the one corresponding to your Python version.

Answer (score 7):

go to the pyscripter shortcut : right click then select *Properties*,
add the option to the target : `--PYTHONXX`
wherein XX the `Python` *version*.

> ex : "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\PyScripter.exe" --PYTHON24

Copy/paste another shortcut and modify the option to another python version.

Comment: similar question, I have ver 2.7.5 (in osgeo) and ver 2.7.10 (pyscripter), how do I get pyscripter to use 2.7.5?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to change the python version in PyScripter is:

> Run->Python Version-> Setup Python Versions->Add New Python Version->
>   **Browse to your python exe and select ok**.-> Click on Activate Selected Python Version..

Now restart your PyScriptor and your are good to go.

[image: Select python selector option]
[image: Choose python version]

[image: Select default python version]