# How to change pyscripter to use Python installed in non-standard directory

Tags: pyscripter

I'm trying configure PyScripter 2.5.3 to use a version of Python that is installed in a non-standard install location (i.e., c:\MyProj\Python27).

*NOTE: I also have ActivePython 26 and 27 also installed, in the default locations c:\python26 and c:\python27)*

I have a short program that simply dumps the python path to verify that I have the correct version:

```
import sys; print( "\n".join(sys.path) )
```

When I'm using the "desired version", I'll see *"c:\MyProj\Python27\lib"* show up on the path.

I've looked at several postings (one is [How to change the version of python that pyscripter uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155392/how-to-change-the-version-of-python-that-pyscripter-uses)) and most just say the defaults work and the defaults do work.  I'm trying to use a non-default directory.

I've used Tools | Configure Tools to set the Python Interpreter, and Command Prompt to run "MyProj" version of python.

So Tools | Python Interpreter, starts c:\MyProj\Python27\python.exe
Also Tools | Command Prompt, starts c:\MyProj\Python27\python.exe version.

But I can't get the Python IDE to use the desired version when I use "Run | Debug (F9)".

I've configured Tools | Options | IDE Options | Python engine type = peRemote.
I've also tried internal.

I've tried starting PyScripter from the command line with the following options (none of these examples worked)

```
...\PyScripter.exe --python27 --pythondllpath=C:\MyProj\Python27
...\PyScripter.exe --python27 --pythondllpath=C:\MyProj\Python27\python27.dll

...\PyScripter.exe --python27 --pythondllpath C:\MyProj\Python27
...\PyScripter.exe --python27 --pythondllpath C:\MyProj\Python27\python27.dll
```

I've tried having only my version of python on the windows PATH (removing c:\Python27)

```
set PATH=C:\MyProj\Python27;%PATH%
...\PyScripter.exe
```

This has also failed to work.

Has anyone had success at using a non-standard location?  If so what steps were followed?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but those are the two ways I did it:


**WAY 1 (The best of two)** 
Go to PyScripter>>Tools>>Options...>>Custom Parameters... and add the following values

```
     1. PythonDir = C:\Program Files\CustomPythonInstallation
     2. PythonExe = C:\Program Files\CustomPythonInstallation\python.exe
     3. PythonVer = 3.3.3
     Note: Adapt the Name = Value pairs above to your case.
```

And close the window with OK button.
Now select PyScripter>>Run>>Python Engine>>Remote and your are ready to go.


**WAY 2 (The more temporary solution)**

- Go to PyScripter>>Run>>Configure External Run...
- set the "Application:" field to your python.exe file
- Close the window with OK button.
- Make sure you run your scripts with PyScripter>>Run>>External Run (Alt+F9)

I hope this helped, good luck.

Comment: I am using Anaconda with 2.7 as default Python, and I have created another Python 3.3 env. My PC is running in Win7 64-bit, above 1st way not work, it reports error saying could not connect to remote Python engine server, the 2nd way does not support blank space in directory to my Python script (also fail).

Comment: This did not work for me. I got the error "could not connect to the remote python engine server" when reinitializing the engine

Answer (score 0):

I'm using two different pythons, tried to use pyscripter with both, but it kept messing up. My simple solution was to download the standalone pyscripter that doesn't use the registry, put copies into two different directories, then set each up for the different py. You can then right click on their icons and set them to start in the proper directories. You can also make two cmd icons and set them respectively so you have a command line. The command line icon can also be set to start in your working directory, although that's normally one level below python, and if it isn't on the path, you have to type ../python to get it (or use a keyboard macro for that.) This works trouble free.

I did delete both pythons and removed them from the system path just in case pyscripter looked for them. Then I installed 2.7 and set up the first scripter. I installed 34 and set up the second. Oddly, the scripters found the correct py each time - I imagine they go for the highest one. But you can also set that in scripter options. And frankly, it may not be necessary to delete py**. If not deleting them doesn't work you can just make a fresh copy of scripter and try again, since that will be a new standalone. For all I know you can reinstall python on the path once pyscripter is set up for each. I haven't tried that. Fiddle around. You can always make a new copy of the pyscripter standalone directory if things don't work out ;')

The interactions between the registry, the path, and the installed pyscripter just led to too many headaches.

Oh, pyscripter doesn't seem to play well with 3.4 but there's a fixed exe for your 3.4 standalone, here - just replace the 3.4 standalone python.exe with this one:
https://pyscripter.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=7680027000&name=PyScripter-Updated.7z&token=ABZ6GAd40xS88r5vwgY9m8Y18vSFKN8q3g%3A1421517339924

Comment: I agree with you, I also tried the portable way suggested in [official FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_use_PyScripter_with_Portable_%28Movable%29_Python?), give it up in despair.